# How to remove repeated words between two strings in python?

Tags: python, string

I'm working in a project with OCR. After some operations I have two strings like that:

```
s1 = "This text is a test of"
s2 = "a test of the reading device"
```

I would like to know how can I remove the repetead words of the second string. My idea is to find the position of the word that is repeated in each list. I tried this:

```
e1 = [x for x in s1.split()]
e2 = [y for y in s2.split()]

for i, item2 in enumerate(e2):
    if item2 in e1:
        print i, item2 #repeated word and index in the first string
        print e1.index(item2) #index in the second string
```

Now I have the repeated words and their position in the first and second list. I need it to compare word to word if these are in the same order. This because may happen that the same word appear two or more times in the string (future validation).

At the end I would like to have a final string like that:

```
ns2 = "the reading device"    
sf= "This text is a test of the reading device"
```

I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Comment: Documentation exists. Please use it. https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: Use `e1.index(item2)` to find out where item2 is in e1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an another attempt,

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as sq
match = sq(None, s1, s2).find_longest_match(0, len(s1), 0, len(s2))
```

**Result**

```
print s1 + s2[match.b+match.size:]
```

> This text is a test of the reading device

Comment: It works fine but what happens if I have something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624787/how-to-delete-invalid-characters-between-multiple-strings-in-python/41624839#41624839). I hope that you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?
`' '.join([x for x in s1.split(' ')] + [y for y in s2.split(' ') if y not in s1.split(' ')])`

I haven't test it carefully but this may be a good idea for dealing with such kind of demands.

Comment: It will remove the all occurring word in second string.

Comment: Won't it only remove those that already exist in the first one?

Comment: `s1 = 'hi are you there'` and `s2 = 'you there hi for'` try this inputs, It will make sense for you.

Comment: As @RahulKP said. When the same word appear two or more times in the string it doesn't work.