# How to delete invalid characters between multiple strings in python?

Tags: python, string, ocr, difflib, sequencematcher

I'm working in a project with OCR in *Spanish*. The camera captures different frames in a line of text. The line of text contains this:

**Este texto, es una prueba del dispositivo lector para no videntes.**

After some operations I get strings like that:

```
s1 = "Este texto, es una p!"
s2 = "fste texto, es una |prueba u.-"
s3 = "jo, es una prueba del dispo‘"
s4 = "prueba del dispositivo \ec"
s5 = "del dispositivo lector par:"
s6 = "positivo lector para no xndev"
s7 = "lector para no videntes"
s8 = "¡r para no videntes."
```

I would like to join the string so that I can get the text of the scanned line in a final string like that:

```
sf = "Este texto, es una prueba del dispositivo lector para no videntes."
```

To begin I tried to use `SequenceMatcher` between two strings but it was not effective:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as sq
s1 = "Este texto, es una p!"
s2 = "fste texto, es una prueba u.-"
match = sq(None, s1, s2).find_longest_match(0, len(s1), 0, len(s2))
print unicode(s1 + s2[match.b + match.size:])
```

The result has invalid characters like `|` or `!`:

```
>>>Este texto, es una p!|prueba u.-
```

Between `s2` and `s3`:

```
>>>fste texto, es una |prueba u.-prueba del dispo‘
```

Etc. I'm using python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex
Do something like

```
import re
line = re.sub(r'\W', r'', line)
```

\W means any none word character. You may read more about regexes at site: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html